# Why would ferrofluid harden?

Tags: magnetism

I recently decided to make my own ferrofluid toy to play with.  I built a sealed enclosure at my local fablab, and the end result was perfect.  It worked just like in the videos you see online, and I couldn't have been more pleased.

But then, after a week or so, I noticed that the fluid was moving a bit more sluggishly, and not long after that, it would barely react to the magnet at all.  Now when I try to play with it, I have to press a big magnet right against the surface, and then the "fluid" moves completely uniformly -- less like a fluid and more like a big black rock.

The only thing I can think is that maybe the suspension fluid I used had a gradual drying-out effect on the ferrofluid.  When I was originally building the thing, I did some googling to find out how best to do it all, and I found an old [post on this very forum](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/409/what-kind-of-suspension-liquid-should-be-used-with-ferrofluid-so-it-does-not-st), suggesting the use of isopropyl alcohol, so that's what I used.  I also used the same type of ferrofluid as the OP in that thread.

So would a different type of suspension fluid keep it from hardening like this? Or am I wrong about the cause?  The only other thing I can think of is that maybe it's because there's a little air bubble in my enclosure.  It can't be any external factors, because it's sealed completely airtight.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: The manufacturers of the ferrofluid actually provide a phone number. It may be a little old-fashioned but you can always try calling them and asking them if the solvent you used is incompatible.

Comment: How about I don't have to click on a link, where I can then guess what *other* link you mean, to find out what you did? ;-)

Comment: Sorry — let me clarify: I’m using FerroFluid EFH-1 by FerroTec - amazingmagnets.com/show-decimal-ferrofluid-0250.aspx